# Rip concert DVD to MP3

Tags: dvd, mp3, dvd-burning

If I have a concert DVD—that I own legitimately—is there any way to rip the tracks to MP3?

The end goal is to get the music onto my iPod and or iPhone, and so if there are any workarounds—short of re-buying the whole concert on iTunes—that would be cool too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC is not only a very good  DVD/video player but it can [extract mp3 audio from any movie](http://www.howtogeek.com/66165/from-the-tips-box-extracting-audio-from-any-video-using-vlc-sneaking-around-paywalls-and-delaying-windows-live-mesh-during-boot./)

For all the options see: http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples

Comment: yes but do you not have to WATCH in real time to do this?

Comment: No, if you use the commandline it will do it as fast as possible

Comment: interesting...do you know of a good tutorial on how this is accomplished. VLC is quite complicated when it comes to these advanced features...learn something new about vlc almost daily

Comment: @MartinBeckett - more importantly, will it rip it right from the DVD, or do I have to convert it to a video file first?

Comment: @Adam - haven't tried from a dvd, just fire up VLC select stream audio and try it!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! what I would do is actualy 2-3 steps but it should work quite well

1. convert dvd to video file with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr)
2. convert video file to mp3 with [miro media converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)
3. (optional) split audio files into seperate tracks (salt to taste) with [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

The way to Convert DVD to MP3 (M4A) audio is displayed in this guide at great length. I have a bunch of DVD concerts, and often rip music from DVD to mp3 in legal way. So I am able to play mp3 on my iPod, iPad, etc.

ImElfin DVD Ripper helps us rip audio from DVD to mp3 in high sound quality. By the way, there are some personalized settings. For example, set output format as iTunes M4A, popular mp3, AAC, etc. And rip any segment from DVD concerts. It provides fast convert speed and fully supports dual core CPU.

Refer to: [Convert Concert DVD to MP3 for iPod](http://www.imelfin.com/how-to-convert-concert-dvd-to-mp3-for-ipod.html#.Uy_uvfmSzh5)